# mysterious apache conf on debian stretch

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, apache2, debian-stretch

I have Apache installed on a Debian Stretch system. I have no sites enabled but for some reason the `/var/www/html/index.html` still renders if I go to `http://hostname`.

Loaded sites:

```
root@hostname:/etc/apache2# a2query -s
No site matches  (disabled by site administrator)
```

The access logs are going to `/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log` which is set in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/other-vhosts-access-log.conf -> ../conf-available/other-vhosts-access-log.conf`:

```
root@hostname:/etc/apache2/conf-enabled# more other-vhosts-access-log.conf
# Define an access log for VirtualHosts that don't define their own logfile
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/other_vhosts_access.log vhost_combined

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

How can I find what setting is doing this? I want to disable that `VirtualHost` so, for now, no page is loaded/rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a default virtual host when Apache is configured. You can disable it by creating a virtual host with a domain name that you want to disable. In the configuration you can tell Apache to return 404 to every request for example.

Comment: oh. i will see if i can figure out how to do that. thank you!